# Client-side-validation with custom model?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, client-side-validation

I use the client-side-validation gem and its simple_form plugin for client-side validation. I have a custom model with `ActiveModel::Validations` included and use simple_form to fill it.

```
<%= simple_form_for @solution, :validate => true, :url => solve_problem_path, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <% @solution.fields.each do |label| %>
    <%= f.input label, :validate => { :presence => true } %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Solve', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Custom model:

```
class Solution < OpenStruct
    include ActiveModel::Validations

    validate do
      @table.each do |key, val|
        errors.add(key, :blank) if val.blank?
      end
    end
    def fields
      @table.keys
    end
  end
```

But client-side-validation doesn't work (server-side does).

Comment: Have you checked for Javascript errors? client-side is dependent on jQuery

Comment: Client-side validation with simple ActiveRecord model work as it should.

Comment: Does client-side-validation support a custom validate block? I thought it only worked for the validates_* helpers.